# How to convert DNAbin to FASTA in R?

Tags: r, fasta, dna-sequence

I am trying to convert `my_dnabin1`, a DNAbin file of 55 samples, to fasta format. I am using the following code to convert it into a fasta file.

`dnabin_to_fasta <- lapply(my_dnabin1, function(x) as.character(x[1:length(x)]))`
This generates a list of 55 samples which looks like:

$SS.11.01

[1] "t" "t" "a" "c" "c" "t" "a" "a" "a" "a" "a" "g" "c" "c" "g" "c" "t" "t" "c" "c" "c" "t" "c" "c" "a" "a"
 [27] "c" "c" "c" "t" "a" "g" "a" "a" "g" "c" "a" "a" "a" "c" "c" "t" "t" "t" "c" "a" "a" "c" "c" "c" "c" "a"

$SS.11.02

[1] "t" "t" "a" "c" "c" "t" "a" "a" "a" "a" "a" "g" "c" "c" "g" "c" "t" "t" "c" "c" "c" "t" "c" "c" "a" "a"
 [27] "c" "c" "c" "t" "a" "g" "a" "a" "g" "c" "a" "a" "a" "c" "c" "t" "t" "t" "c" "a" "a" "c" "c" "c" "c" "a"

and so on...

However, I want a fasta formatted file as the output that may look something like:

`>SS.11.01 ttacctga`

`>SS.11.02 ttacctga`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

`lapply(my_dnabin1, function(x) paste0(x, collapse = ''))`

Comment: Thanks! This solves one part of the question. Now my output looks like: $SS.11.01
[1] "ttacctaaaaagccgcttccctccaaccctagaagcaaacctttcaaccccactatgctgttgcaattgccataaattcagttgtccagccaatccatcttcatttccctgtctcagccttcttaatg" . However, it is still a list and hence every sample name starts with a '$'. I would like to have '>' in place of the '$'. Could you please help me with this?

Comment: It was my first time asking a question and I was not sure which site would be better to ask this. So, I asked this on Stack Exchange, too. A user responded with the following code and it solves the problem: `cat(file="out.fa", paste(paste0(">",names(dnabin_to_fasta)),
          sapply(dnabin_to_fasta, paste, collapse=""), sep="\n"), sep="\n");` I will take care to stick to one site in the future.